# Webservice url of hybris installed in local system

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to form the webservice url for getting order, products etc.details using webservice calls from **Hybris** installed in the local system.

Which all files to be checked to form the url?

**For Example :** http://localhost:9001/../../..

What should be filled in the blanks?

I am using a trail version of **Hybris**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate a webservice extension by the modulegen ant target. This extension provides you a logic how you can make your hybris application reachabel by a webcall.

https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8c83443586691014a4b1ebdb08146283.html - Here is the WIKI Page about webservices

https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8b9e3f1c86691014bd71bdc414663e44.html - Here is an example of a webservice

Comment: It's not mandatory to generated your own implementation, you can use the ootb extensions if you do not need to customize WS.

Answer (score 0):

The list is quite long to be posted here.

Currently you can found v1 WS definition in [Calls Reference - v1](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8b7165a186691014b5569838c0c19e40.html) (check child pages).

The new v2 WS are described in [Calls Reference - v2](https://help.hybris.com/6.2.0/hcd/8b718fba8669101486bb9b02be7b9a7e.html) and extends v1 WS.

Basically for user, cart and order, you can find below the model of URL to call:

```
User resources: https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/{baseSiteID}/users/{userID}/...

Cart resources: https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/{baseSiteID}/users/{userID}/carts/{cartID}...

Order resources: https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/{baseSiteID}/users/{userID}/orders/{orderID}
```